# Fan type for continuous use

Tags: ventilation

Are there specific types of fans (not computer fans) that are intended for continuous use? If so, what are these called?

Comment: `brushless` and `continuous duty`

Comment: It would help to know what sort of fan you *are* asking about. The terminology may be different across different domains where fans may be used. (HVAC, in computers, a household fan, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for brushless and continuous duty. @Romen: any fan for moving air from one room to another, installed inside of a wall (probably in a tube) on a set-it-and-clean-it-once-a-year basis.